# Wordpress using comma in taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

Until the release of PHP 8 I was able to replace "--" with a comma in a custom tag. using the following code.

```
if(!is_admin()){ // make sure the filters are only called in the frontend
    
    $custom_taxonomy_type = 'winners_name'; // here goes your taxonomy type
    
    function comma_taxonomy_filter($tag_arr){
        global $custom_taxonomy_type;
        $tag_arr_new = $tag_arr;
        if($tag_arr->taxonomy == $custom_taxonomy_type && strpos($tag_arr->name, '--')){
            $tag_arr_new->name = str_replace('--',', ',$tag_arr->name);
        }
        return $tag_arr_new;    
    }
    add_filter('get_'.$custom_taxonomy_type, comma_taxonomy_filter);
    
    function comma_taxonomies_filter($tags_arr){
        $tags_arr_new = array();
        foreach($tags_arr as $tag_arr){
            $tags_arr_new[] = comma_taxonomy_filter($tag_arr);
        }
        return $tags_arr_new;
    }
    add_filter('get_the_taxonomies',    comma_taxonomies_filter);
    add_filter('get_terms',             comma_taxonomies_filter);
    add_filter('get_the_terms',         comma_taxonomies_filter);
}
```

After the PHP update it's giving me the following error.
PHP Fatal error:
Uncaught Error:
Undefined constant "comma_taxonomy_filter" in /nas/content/live/stagelask/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php:31\nStack trace:\n#0 /nas/content/live/stagelask/wp-settings.php(591): include()\n#1 /nas/content/live/stagelask/wp-config.php(119): require_once('/nas/content/li...')\n#2 /nas/content/live/stagelask/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/nas/content/li...')\n#3 /nas/content/live/stagelask/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/nas/content/li...')\n#4 /nas/content/live/stagelask/index.php(17): require('/nas/content/li...')\n#5 {main}\n thrown in /nas/content/live/stagelask/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 31, referer: https://stagelask.wpengine.com

I first did some research to see if there was a fix for this. Then I tried (unsuccessfully) to define the constant comma_taxonomy_filter.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: `comma_taxonomy_filter` and `comma_taxonomies_filter` all need to be in quotes. `'comma_taxonomies_filter'` and `'comma_taxonomy_filter'`. I'm closing this as a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only need to fix the second parameter of the `add_filter()` calls to be strings:

```php
add_filter('get_the_taxonomies',    'comma_taxonomies_filter');
add_filter('get_terms',             'comma_taxonomies_filter');
add_filter('get_the_terms',         'comma_taxonomies_filter');
```

Comment: After some QA testing this fix worked for my custom content type. However it's now giving me a warning on the blog post type.  Warning: Attempt to read property "taxonomy" on int in /Users/markhofschneider/Local Sites/lasker/app/public/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 61

Comment: @markhof Please post a separate question.